# How to use oneUI v2.1 red theme on a Domino 9 server?

Tags: themes, xpages

We have a Domino 9.0.1 server and we would like to demo the document Library that uses XPages but we would like to use OneUI v2.1's red theme, as it is an almost perfect fit with the company's color.

I can't get it to work. I must be missing something...  What needs to be done in order to achieve that, if at all possible? I do have the themes copied in the doc Library, but it just uses OneUIv3's default theme regardless of what I choose in the app properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `oneuiv2.1_red` to Application Configuration / Xsp Properties / Application theme in Designer in your database.

[image]

This theme is already available on server so you don't need to put it into your database.

Comment: I totally forgot that there were multiplr tabs on the application properties...   Thanks for reminding me  :)